# How to get connection errors with a queue?

Tags: java, apache-camel, queue, ibm-mq

I`m using apache-camel connection to IBM MQ. if the connection to the queue is not established in the log I get

```
[INFO ] 2019-09-20 13:55:21.983 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - JmsConsumer[QUEUE]] DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - [, TID=, SID=, ] - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
[WARN ] 2019-09-20 13:55:27.178 [Camel (camel-1) thread #23 - JmsConsumer[QUEUE]] DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - [, TID=, SID=, ] - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'QUEUE' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'QUEUE'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2085' ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME').
[INFO ] 2019-09-20 13:55:27.178 [Camel (camel-1) thread #23 - JmsConsumer[QUEUE]] DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - [, TID=, SID=, ] - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
[WARN ] 2019-09-20 13:55:32.286 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - JmsConsumer[QUEUE]] DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - [, TID=, SID=, ] - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'QUEUE' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'QUEUE'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2085' ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME').
[INFO ] 2019-09-20 13:55:32.287 [Camel (camel-1) thread #6 - JmsConsumer[QUEUE]] DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer - [, TID=, SID=, ] - Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

Im trying use

```
from(queue1).processor(exchange -> {"some code"}).to(queue2).
onException(Throwable.class).proccess(exchange -> {"some code"})
```

and

```
public class camelError implements ErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

this does not work

How can I catch and handle a com.ibm.mq.MQException connection exception and get the queue name?

Comment: The error suggests that the queue name used is incorrect i.e. object unknown. Could you talk to your organizations MQ admin and get the right details to see exactly what is the queue name. Also, you could go through the following link => http://lowry-techie.blogspot.com/2010/11/camel-integration-with-websphere-mq.html

Answer (score 3):

> compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2085' 
>   ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME').

Did you look up that MQ Reason Code in the [MQ Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q040710_.htm)?  You clearly have a configuration error.  How are you defining your JMS queue to IBM MQ queue?  i.e. are you using MQ JNDI.  Where do you define "queue1" and "queue2"?

Comment: Yes i have configuration error. I need to catch this **compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2085' ('MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME').** exception and process it programmatically.